# Setting font in Android custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, typeface

I use a custom Layout for displaying my ListView Items.
But when I try to set font at RunTime app crashes.
First I tried to access the Texviews of the layout in onCreate... seeing that it wont work, I looked for answers online and found out that I should be doing the setting in my custom Adapter. I tried that too, same result.

My adapter looks like this:

```
public class VizitaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Vizita>{
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Typeface fontux = null;

  public VizitaAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Vizita[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        fontux = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/myrprocond.otf"); 
    }


 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;
 ...
 ...
        ((TextView)row).setTypeface(fontux);
        return row;
 }
```

So when my activity should start, I receive an error message that crashes the app. Before this, the app worked fine.
What am I doing wrong?
I should be able to set different textViews to different TypeFaces. That is actually what I need. But I cannot even set all textViews at once...

Please help.
Thank you

UPDATE
Logs are bellow

`08-01 16:57:22.727: D/szipinf(881): Initializing inflate state
08-01 16:57:22.787: D/AndroidRuntime(881): Shutting down VM
08-01 16:57:22.787: W/dalvikvm(881): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at softwarex.ssmmonitor_custom.VizitaAdapter.getView(VizitaAdapter.java:50)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-01 16:57:22.797: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 16:57:24.657: I/Process(881): Sending signal. PID: 881 SIG: 9`

I have no idea how to format the log to look more readable :(

Also I changed the Code above to reflect the latest try (which also gave me this error)

Comment: I would recommend using this style for adapters. Use holder and check if the convertView is null : http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/#ViewHolder-Pattern

Comment: What is 50 line in VizitaAdapter.java?

Comment: This line: ((TextView)row).setTypeface(fontux);

Comment: It seems that type of `row` is `RelativeLayout` and it cannot be casted to `TextView`. If so you should use `findViewById` to get TextViews and set font them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, attach log. 
Most likely you have an `NullPointerException` on  this line:

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourfont.ttf"); 
((TextView)row).setTypeface(face);
```

`convertView` may be `null` and you should create a new one in this case or call the method `getView` of the super class([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29))

Comment: I also think that the problem is in line `Typeface fontux = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/myrprocond.otf");`. I removed all other references to the Typeface setting from the holder and if I uncomment this line the app crashes. If I comment it, then app works. So I guess this is where the problem lies. But why? And how to solve?

Comment: I must post the logs in the question (they are too long). In 10 seconds they will be there. Done

Comment: @user1137313 [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34643/room-for-esentsov-and-user1137313)

Comment: I solved my problem. it is:` holder.txtLoco.setTypeface(fontu);
        return row;
}`

Comment: So before returning row, where I assign holder contents... I can set for each textView the Typeface I want. This way I can set different typefaces for different textViews. Thank you very much for your help.